# Test-Path -include not working with -LiteralPath

Tags: powershell

Why do the below commands return different results?

```
PS: SQL 2012> Test-Path -LiteralPath .\ssis_2012_deployment_script_x64.ps1 -Include *.ispac
True

PS: SQL 2012> Test-Path -Path .\ssis_2012_deployment_script_x64.ps1 -Include *.ispac
False
```

The file `ssis_2012_deployment_script_x64.ps1` exists in the current directory. I would expect the result to be `False` for both calls, but for some reason using `-LiteralPath` causes it to return `True`.

Comment: `-LiteralPath` means "don't do wildcards, they're not wildcards, they're literal characters". I don't see what sense it makes to use `-Include` with it, and I'm guessing it disables/ignores `Include/Exclude` and since your path does exist, you get a `True`. I can't work out from the PS source whether that's right or not which is why this is a speculative comment instead of an answer. With `-Path` you are asking it to find a `.ps1` file but it's qualifying that with a wildcard looking for *`.ispac` files and finds nothing matching both restrictions, so you get `False`.

Comment: Compare `Test-Path -Path .\test.txt -Include *.txt` (True) and `Test-Path -Path .\test.txt -Exclude *.txt` (False), and how that doesn't work with `-LiteralPath`

Answer (score 0):

`-Include` has no impact on `-LiteralPath`

Check out the [help description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-6#optional-parameters):

> Specifies paths that this cmdlet tests. The value of this parameter qualifies the *Path* parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as "*.txt". Wildcard characters are permitted.